# Future prediction

Tags: grammar

> It has been snowing since morning and I am afraid it won't have stopped by Friday.

Is it correct and if not, why?
Can we use future perfect tense for that kind of sentences?

Comment: You can. Most people won't. It's perfectly grammatical, but you're more likely to hear "I'm afraid it won't stop by Friday".

Comment: Thanks, yes I would say so as well but now I am a bit confused is their any rules?

Comment: You can use the perfect for an event that occurs in the interval before a specific endpoint (which is Friday, in the example).

Comment: It is correct.  There are other ways one might word it, but nothing wrong with the above.  As to rules, "2 + 2 = 4" and "1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 4".  Both are equally correct and one is no better than the other -- they're just different.

Answer (score -1):

The idea found in the sentence

> It has been snowing since morning and I am afraid it won't have stopped by Friday.

has a redundancy, because these two phrases are equivalent:

1. it won't have stopped on Friday
2. it won't stop by Friday

Language tenses are best looked at from the Event-State perspective.

An event is mostly [punctiliar](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/punctiliar) (occurring at a point in time/space). And event is exercised on an object to effect change in the state of the object.

A state is a window or range of time/space flanked by two events.

For example

- Event 1: door is made
- State 1: door is unpainted
- Event 2: painting the door has started
- State 2: door is being painted
- Event 3: painting the door has completed
- State 3: the door is painted.

State 3 of the door now accords it the privilege to be addressed as a *painted door*.

Let's analyse your "snowing having stopped" hypothetical timeline.

- Act 1 Scene 1: It is Tues morning
- **Event 1**: Start of Act 1: Scene 1
- **State 1**: snowing since don't know when, howling winds since don't know when
- Act 1: Scene 2: Wed
- Still in state 1: snowing and howling winds since Tues morning
- Act 1: Scene 3: Thu
- **Event 2**: Howling winds stop
- **State 2**: Howling winds have stopped, but still snowing
- Act 1: Scene 4: Fri midnite
- Still in state 2
- Act 2: Scene 1: Sat 11 am
- **Event 3**: Snowing stops.
- **State 3**: Snowing has stopped (+ howling winds have stopped)
- Act 2: Scene 2: Sat 11.05 am: State 3.
- Act 2: Scene 3: Sat evening: State 3.
- Act 3: Scene 1: Time-travelling machine brings you back to Act 1: Scene 2.

This is the set of observations you can declare in Act 1: Scene 2:

- Howling winds will have stopped on Friday.
- Which is equivalent to saying, Howling winds will stop by Friday.
- Snowing will not have stopped on Friday.
- Which is equivalent to saying, Snowing will not stop by Friday.

Wait a minute - you are able to use assertive verb "will" because either you had traveled back in time from Saturday, or you've had a lot of experience with the weather in that region.

What if you received a weather report from a source that has had 40% hit rate? And you had not travelled back in time. Then you would shift into the hypothetical/imaginary mode (aka subjunctive mode) of thinking.

Given that the weather would behave as predicted ...

- The howling winds would stop by Friday. That is, it would have stopped on Friday.
- The snowing would not stop by Friday. That is, the snowing would not have stopped on Friday.

Comment: I like the tools of your analysis, and how you performed it. The only thing I wonder about is the alleged "redundancy". As far as I can see no information is duplicated. Yes, there is another, less complicated way to say it, but mere complication is not redundancy.

Comment: I'm afraid you have a restricted understanding of the term *redundancy*. You only understood the term *redundancy* from all the articles you've read about avoiding redundant repetition. You do not have the exposure to the systemic understanding of redundancy being a fail-safe mechanism in engineering.

Comment: "I'm afraid you have a restricted understanding of the term redundancy." Well, I most likely have a restricted understanding of almost everything due to my being a mere mortal ;-). But can you be more specific in this particular case? When I look the word up (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/redundancy), repetition or duplication of function or information seems to be the core meaning. I still cannot see how that concept applies the OP's use of the future perfect.

Comment: Parallel redundancy=two systems/engine functioning simultaneously, to ensure the failure of one will not cause the loss of function. Sequential/backup redundancy=when one fails, the other takes over. Functional redundancy=where two functions crisscross each other, without regard to intents to be redundant, but nevertheless whose incident redundancy increases the robustness of a system.

Comment: "Anna is a vegetarian. She will not kill a pig. She eats kosher too." Are three functionally incidental redundant statements. The functional redundancy ensures there is no way that Anna would harm a pig.

Comment: "It won't have stopped on Friday", besides providing temporally displaced subjunctive mode, has a second statement embedded in it by implication "it will not stop by Friday." By finding the 2nd function of the statement embedded, it presents a double whammy argument. Because first you would have to argue against the idea that the snow stops before Friday. 2nd, you then have to argue against the idea that  the snow stops after Friday.

Comment: I thought you say the two wordings are *equivalent*, per the first sentence in your answer? That is not the same as having "a second meaning being embedded" in the OP's sentence, as per your last comment. Just that I can word the OP's statement differently certainly does not imply redundancy -- almost every statement can be worded differently.

Comment: I could not justify putting so much explanation in the answer. *Equivalence* was the least of evil of being imprecise.